# Probability of having A & B before C & D in a sequence of A-Z

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a sequence of all the letters $A-Z$ where each letter appears only once. I need to find the probability that the letters $A$ and $B$ will appear before the letters $C$ and $D$. The letters don't have to appear one after the other nor is there any meaning to their order, i.e $ABCD$ and $BADC$ are both acceptable.

I tried solving this by defining: $E_1=A$ appears before $C$, $E_2=A$ appears before $D$, $E_3=B$ appears before $C$, $E_4=A$ appears before $D$. So what I need to find is $P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3\cap E_4)$. I know that $$P(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3\cup E_4) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+P(E_3)+P(E_4)-P(E_1\cap E_2)-P(E_1\cap E_3)-P(E_1\cap E_4)-P(E_2\cap E_3)-P(E_2\cap E_4)-P(E_3\cap E_4)+P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)+P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_4)+P(E_1\cap E_3\cap E_4)+P(E_2\cap E_3\cap E_4)-P(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3\cap E_4)$$ but now I have a problem I don't know how to calculate the other probabilities needed.

Comment: To clarify:  $ACBD$ and $ACDB$ both do not qualify, correct?

Comment: I suspect this is the same as the probability  that the letters $A$ and $B$ will appear before the letters $C$ and $D$ in a permutation from $A,B,C,D$, which may be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply stated, $AB$ or $BA$ appear before $CD$ or $DC$.

Consider $$(1)(2)(3)(4)$$

$A$, $B$ can be filled in spots $1$, $2$ in two ways. Similarly $C$, $D$ in spots $3$, $4$ in two ways.

Now put the remaining letters in five gaps.

$$()(1)()(2)()(3)()(4)()$$

Required probability is $$\dfrac{2\cdot2\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdots26}{26!}=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{6}}$$

There is shorter route through realization that placement of $A,B,C,D$ is independent of arrangements of remaining $22$ letters. Hence probability $=$ $$\dfrac{2\cdot2}{4!}=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{6}}$$

Comment: if I follow your way I get that I have $5^22$ ways for distributing the letters between the gaps so the probability is $P=\frac{5^{22} * 2 * 2}{26!}=2.364727271E-11$ which seems rather slim

Comment: @CforLinux, When you put one more letter, say $G$, the number of gaps increase by $1$. So its $5\cdot6\cdot7\cdots$ instead of $5^{22}$.

Answer (score 0):

The other letters do not affect the probability, so all we have to consider is the possible orderings of $\{A,B,C,D\}$.  There are $4!$ possible orderings, all of which we assume are equally likely, and in only $4$ of them do $A$ and $B$ precede $C$ and $D$.  So the probability is
$$\frac{4}{4!}$$